# Expandable list indicator icon in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, indicator

I have expandable list view in my Navigation Drawer. I am trying set an icon and make it show to it's right.

I have two questions:

1. What should be the size of the indicator icon? 32 * 32? shows blurred, I want to have simple plus icon and minus icon.
2. Also I am trying to place the indicator icon to the right? I am not able to do that?

I have tried all the ways but didn't work here is one of it:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    width = metrics.widthPixels;

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) 
    {
        expListView.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetDipsFromPixel(50), width - GetDipsFromPixel(10));
    } 
    else 
    {
        expListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(width - GetDipsFromPixel(50), width - GetDipsFromPixel(10));
    }
}
```

I am testing the app on Nexus 5(5.0) and Galaxy Nexus (4.3).

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved the issue myself. Hope the below answer will be useful for somebody who is struggling to move the group indicator to right etc..

Instead of "android:groupIndicator" I added a imageView in the group list.

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/expandableIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/plus"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
```

Then in the BaseExpandableListAdapter the place where groupView is called:

I used :

```
        if(groupPosition != -1)
        {
            int imageResourceId = isExpanded ? R.drawable.plus : R.drawable.minus;
            image.setImageResource(imageResourceId);
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } 
        else 
        {
            image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

The above is just a work around instead of default group indicator. This solves the issue.

Still not able to figure out the actual size for groupindicator? as of now I am using 25*25 seems to be coming nice but I would say there should be some better size to show good quality.

Thanks!